# RAML definition reusable sub-route

Tags: rest, raml

Our api will have a reusable `/posts` subroute that will apply to different top-level routes.

For example:

```
/me/posts 
/users/{user-id}/posts
...
```

Example for posts:

```
/posts 
    /{post-id}
        /likes 
        /comments 
            /{comment-id}
...
```

Posts will have fixed subroutes, parameters etc as well.
What is the standard way to define such a default, reusable subroute with RAML?

Of course, one could decide to turn this around and make a /posts endpoint, but I don't think that the API definition should be changed based on RAML capabilities. Also, I should be able to have multiple endpoints pointing to the same resource, if I wanted it to.

If you have an answer, please share an **example** according the requirements.

Answer (score 3):

You can define a ResourceType and specify you are using it in many places. You can do this in the same file or in an external file opreating as a Library.

http://raml.org/developers/whats-new-raml-10

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work well. RecourceTypes are there as a level of abstraction in the form of inheritance. What I want is to add a custom subroute to different endpoints. Traits don't seem to work well either.